# Serial port field greyed out with error on launch (Ubuntu 14,04)

Tags: serial

I know this has been asked several times already, but I've nevered seen it asked with an error included on launch.

Here is the message that comes up in the terminal when I launch arduino (with root privileges if thats relevant):

(java:9042): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_connection_get_unique_name: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

When I try to compile the code, it gives me the standard, "COM1 NOT FOUND" and a bunch of other errors. I can post the entire error message here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the serial port.

Comment: Are you in the `dialout` group (if I remember what ubuntu calls it) so you have permission to open the serial ports?

Comment: Yes, I am in the dialout group.